# How to unzip multiple folders with FME 2014

Tags: fme-form, compression

I have downloaded 21 zipped folders using the *HttpFetcher* transformer and I cannot figure out how to get FME to unzip these files.

I've seen some posts about using either the *TclCaller* or *PythonCaller* transformer, but I've tried that without luck.

Does anyone out there know how to unzip directories, using FME?

Comment: Depending on the format you just need to add the reader and it will automatically unzip the file when reading features in.

Comment: Yes, if you just want to read the contents of the files with FME then you can point a reader at them. Otherwise the easier option would be the SystemCaller transformer I think.

Answer (score 1):

This one's a little trickier than it probably should be.

Your options are as follows.

**Reader/FeatureReader**

If the zip files you want to read are fixed, you can you/should use a Reader/Feature Reader. These can decrypt the zip file automatically.

You may also be interested in this Community Answer which covers the structure of zip files: http://fmepedia.safe.com/AnswersQuestionDetail?id=906a0000000cl94AAA

**HttpFetcher**

If you must use a HttpFetcher, you will need to write the contents of the response to your disk before unzipping it. You do this with an AttributeFileWriter. Then there are various options for unzipping:

- a FeatureReader, as above (optimal)
- some Python (i.e.: `exec unzip -oq @Value(_ZipFileName)`) followed by a FeatureReader (suboptimal)

For more information on the process see:
http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Read-Zip-File-from-URL-as-Source-Data-for-Workspace ; *However, Note that this is dated 2011, so doesn't account for the fact that FME as of 2013 supports native ZIP file reading with Readers.*